# VB WPF How to handle a click event on a context menuItem in an object in a resourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I've just started out using WPF so bear with me.

I'm using ready built NotifyIcon replacement for WPF in Visual Basic 2015.
(http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon)

I've read the docs (they are in c# though...)  and initially configured it in a resourceDictionary.

```
    <ResourceDictionary               
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SystemTrayTest"
xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
   >
   <!-- Globally declared notify Icon -->
     <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="MyNotifyIcon"
              IconSource="/Icons/Error.ico" 
              ToolTipText="Project Activity Recorder"  >
         <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu
      Background="LightCoral">
      <MenuItem x:Name="CA" Header="Current Activity"/>
      <MenuItem Header="New Activity" />
      <MenuItem Header="Manage Activities" />
      <Separator />
      <MenuItem Header="Manage Companies" />
      <MenuItem Header="Manage Projects" />
      <MenuItem Header="Manage Users" />
      <Separator />
      <MenuItem Header="Exit" />
    </ContextMenu>
  </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
     </tb:TaskbarIcon>
   </ResourceDictionary>
```

I kick off the NotifyIcon by instantiating it in Application_Startup Event.

```
  tb = CType(FindResource("MyNotifyIcon"), TaskbarIcon)
```

This shows the SystemTray icon fine with a context menu.

However, I can't figure out how to pick up when a user selects from the content Menu.

I've programmed in windows forms before but as I have mentioned WPF is new to me. I can suss out how to do this from a WPF form but I'm beginning to think its because I've set up the NotifyIcon in the resourceDictionary.

I would appreciate some friendly guidance.

Many thanks All!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045718/wpf-events-in-resourcedictionary-for-a-controltemplate) for a ResourceDictionary to have a code behind. However, in this case, I doubt that it will be useful to you because I am pretty sure you will need something from your window.

If that's not a requirement, you can just use the code behind of the resource dictionary.

Comment: What's the alternative?  To programmatically configure the tb object in the startup event?

Comment: You could put it in the MainWindow itself, instead of a ResourceDictionary. The purpose of a resource dictionary is reusing it. If you _can_ reuse it, you can make a code behind for the resource dictionary. Else you can put it in the window itself.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm using a startup event to start and initialise my application and that doesn't have a window.  Would it just be best to use a window to initialise (so I can configure the toolbar object) and not use the startup event?

Comment: I added it to the mainWindow but now as the TaskBarIcon is there. I can't refer to it from another wpf window.  Humph! Windows Forms was much easier. :-)

Comment: Nope. Winforms is not easier. You can simply pass a reference of your window to another window just as you do with Forms.

Comment: And you are right.  Many thanks Emperor Aiman.  I created an instance of the form to be opened and before showing it I copied over a reference to the current window and it worked.

Comment: I think this has shown me that jumping from WPF from winforms is achievable but requires a fair bit of learning.  Thanks SO much for your help.

Comment: No problem. There are lots of articles designed for winforms developers to embrace WPF. It's really great. When I learned WPF, I never looked back. Everything becomes so easy once you get a hold of it