# Handle an Event From a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have 8 Custom Radiobuttons Styled as shown bellow

```
<Style x:Key="RadioSubMenuTbox" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource fontIbtisam}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <Border Name="brdMenu" CornerRadius="0" Background="#20000000" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="RadioContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <TextBox Name="txtM" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,5,4,5" Style="{StaticResource txtboxDefaultNoShadow}" Grid.Column="1" Width="100"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="txtM" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="brdMenu" Property="Background" Value="#F2826A" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="brdMenu" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#F2826A"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="brdMenu" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When a `RadioButton` IsChecked a textbox within the `RadioButton` is made visible, now the style is in a ResourceDictionary file, and i want to handle the TextChanged Event of each Textbox.

I can access the `TextBox` as follow

```
TextBox aTBox = (TextBox)MyRButton.Template.FindName("txtM", MyContentControl);
```

But how to handle the TextChanged Event ?

Comment: A `ResourceDictionary` can have code behind just like Windows, you could add an event handler and call the textchanged from there.

Comment: after you found `aTBox` element, add event handler: `aTBox.TextChanged += (sender, e) => { /*Do Smth*/};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ResourceDictionary` can have code behind just like Windows, you could add an event handler and call the textchanged from there, for example :

1. Add a new Class in visual studio in the same folder of your `ResourceDictionary`
2. Add the `x:Class` attribute to the XAML file

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary x:Class="YourNameSpace.YourClass"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   ```
3. Now add the Event handler to your `TextBox` txtM

For more details you can check [Fredrik Hedblad's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7046016/2832222)